# How do I add multiple roles at registration?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add 2 roles to user at registration.
Role 1- One of 2 default, already preset roles.
Role 2- Individually generated for every user at their registration.

When assigning default role only- assigns no problem.
When i'm adding dynamically generated roles, it assigns this role only, missing the default one.

```
    $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    $getuser = new WP_User($user); 
    $getuser->set_role('profile_1');
    add_role( 
    'user-ID'.$user, 
    __( 'user-ID'.$user, 'wordpress-66604-809452.cloudwaysapps.com' ), 
    array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
    ));
    $getuser->set_role('user-ID'.$user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i'm reading set_role removes the roles and assign the new one ONLY, it seems like what you described

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#set_role.28.24role.29

### Set Role

set_role($role)
Set the role of the user.

This will remove the previous roles of the user and assign the user the new one. You can set the role to an empty string and it will remove all of the roles from the user.

Parameters 
role (string) - role name.
Returns 
Nothing
Since 
2.0.0
Related actions

### Add Role

add_role( $role )
Add role to user.

Updates the user's meta data option with capabilities and roles.

Parameters 
role (string) - role name.